# How to access entry in the javascript object array

Tags: php, jquery

I assigned a JSON result from php to a javascript variable. 
The result returned looks like below but it gives me **undefined** **undefined**

```
[{"a":"2","u":"jamesoduro","l":"Oduro","f":"James"},{"a":"5","u":"deary.grace","l":"Grace","f":"Dear"}]
```

I simple know this look like a javascript array with two objects.
I am trying to access the data inside the objects but to no avail. 
Below is script:

**PHP**

```
    <?php   

//fetch  online users
$array  = array();
$sql    = "SELECT id as a,username as u, lastname as l,firstname as f FROM users WHERE active =1 limit 2";
$q      = mysqli_query($dbc_conn,$sql);

while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $array[]    = $row; 

}

$json = json_encode($array);    
echo $json;


?>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //checking online users
    setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"testing.php",
        type:"post",
        success:function(response){

            var array = response;
            console.log(array[0].f +" "+ array[0].l);
        }
    });
},200);

});
```

Please what could be the problem?? Thank you

Comment: Given what you've shown your code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/uwtr3q7j/. Try `contentType: "application/json"` in the AJAX request to force jQuery to deserialise the JSON for you (although it should do this itself if the response has the correct MIME type set) and check that `response` is an object with `console.log(typeof response)`

Comment: Try `var array = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: yes ..that is when you copy the result and try accessing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deserializing the response:

```
var array = JSON.parse(response);
```

**EXPLANATION**

The response you get from the ajax call is of type **string**, so you have to convert it to an **object**. That's what JSON.parse() method do: it parses the JSON string and creates the object that this string represent, following specific rules (The parsed string must be in a [valid](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) **JSON format**).

Comment: thanks..this works ...can you please tell me what the JSON.parese() do and why u used it??

Answer (score 2):

```
 $.ajax({
    url:"testing.php",
    type:"post",
    success:function(response){

        var array = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log(array[0].f +" "+ array[0].l);
    }
});
```

You get a string from php , need turn the string into a json object .

You have to learn to debug your code to find what is going wrong I guess .

Answer (score 1):

Keep your server side PHP script code neat and clean

1. Start PHP block from first character of first line.
2. Do not close php block if there is no output in HTML format.
3. Use ob_clean() function before echo output in  is your are in developer mode and display error is enabled.

for example

```
ob_clean();
echo json_encode($array);
```

In client side, if you are getting JSON response in ajax, pass `dataType:'json'` in ajax option

```
$.ajax({
    url:"testing.php",
    type:"post",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response[0].f +" "+ response[0].l);
    }
});
```